# How can I create PHP SOAP request to look like this?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

with php i want to create request , that xml should look like this,
i am using web service test tool and its working fine while i post below xml to it,
i just want to know i can i create soap request exactly like this ?
[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader transactionID="000032" primaryLangID="E" timeStamp="2008-12-09T09:55:16.3618750-05:00" xmlns="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/Core/">
      <Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
      <Destination entityID="TI" systemType="ORS" />
    </OGHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AvailabilityRequest xmlns:a="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/Availability/" xmlns:hc="http://webservices.test.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/" summaryOnly="true" xmlns="http://webservices.test.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl">
      <a:AvailRequestSegment availReqType="Room" numberOfRooms="1" totalNumberOfGuests="1" totalNumberOfChildren="0">
        <a:StayDateRange>
          <hc:StartDate>2013-10-05T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</hc:StartDate>
          <hc:EndDate>2013-10-06T00:00:00.0000000-05:00</hc:EndDate>
        </a:StayDateRange>
        <a:HotelSearchCriteria>
          <a:Criterion>
            <a:HotelRef chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="AXAMUM" />
          </a:Criterion>
        </a:HotelSearchCriteria>
      </a:AvailRequestSegment>
    </AvailabilityRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

EDIT:
php Code added.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);


require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("http://###.###.###.##:8080/ws_ws_51/Availability.asmx?wsdl");
$err = $client->getError();
echo "<pre>";

if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    exit();
}
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('Availability', array('name' => 'Scott'));
// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

this code o/p :

**Error**

Charset from HTTP Content-Type 'UTF-8' does not match encoding from XML declaration 'iso-8859-1'

Comment: Yes, you can. Oh wait, do you want us to write it? That'll not work. Try yourself, have a look at http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php and come back when you've got furthermore questions.

Comment: @akluth i have added my code which throws following error !

Comment: You might want to try the PHP extension SOAP. In my opinion, it's much easier. (As suggested by akluth)